# I'm trying to display my child comments in VueJs its giving me a small error

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Hi i am i just started VueJs and i am having difficulties at the same time.**
I'm working on a Laravel + VueJs project and I'm in the blogging and commenting system.
On this I created a comments table in which I have the **"respond_to_id"** attribute which will store the **"id"** of the parent comments.
Then at VueJs level I retrieve these parent and child comments.
But the problem is with the VueJs display. As I answer only to a child comment this last one this last comment does not display below this child comment.

Here is my Vue.Js code for retrieving child comments.

```
<div
                v-for="(commentaire, i) in commentaires"
                :key="i"
                v-if="commentaires.length"
              >
                <div id="comment-1" class="comment">
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="comment-img">
                      <img v-bind:src="commentaire.photo" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <h5>
                        <a href="">{{ commentaire.name }}</a>
                        <a @click="repondre(commentaire)" class="reply"
                          ><i class="bi bi-reply-fill"></i> répondre</a
                        >
                      </h5>
                      <time datetime="2020-01-01"
                        >il y a {{ format(commentaire.created_at) }}</time
                      >
                      <p>
                        {{ commentaire.contenu }}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End comment #1 -->

                <div
                  id="comment-reply-1"
                  class="comment comment-reply"
                  v-for="child in commentaire.children"
                  :key="child.id"
                  v-bind:commentaire="child"
                >
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="comment-img">
                      <img v-bind:src="child.photo" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <h5>
                        <a href="">{{ child.name }}</a>
                        <a @click="repondre(child)" class="reply"
                          ><i class="bi bi-reply-fill"></i> répondre</a
                        >
                      </h5>
                      <time datetime="2020-01-01">{{
                        format(child.created_at)
                      }}</time>
                      <p>
                        {{ child.contenu }}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- End comment reply #2-->
                </div>
              </div>
```

I wonder where the error lies. Help me please.

Comment: Perhaps you could share what the error is...

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFOA.png)

The problem is that when I reply to a child comment my comment does not show below the child comment.

Comment: You can just edit your original question instead of positing an answer if you want to add additional information.

Comment: Poster added additional information to his/her question as an answer.